# ZipArchieve fails with ArgumentException when stream position is reset

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I have multiple `Stream` instances and would like to zip them up using `ZipArchive`. This is the code I'm using:

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();            
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var stream in streams)
    {
        var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry($"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpeg");

        using var entryStream = entry.Open();
        stream.CopyTo(entryStream);           
    }
}

memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
// memoryStream.Position = 0; // this throws the same exception
```

This code works fine when `streams` has a few items, but it fails with 10 items. The error is coming from the last line when I try to rewind back to the initial position.

> {System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for
> the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index
> to the end of the source collection.   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read
> (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int…}

This is the memory stream state in debugger:

```
CanRead: true
CanSeek: true
CanWrite: true
Capacity: 8534016
Length: 6853402
Position: 6853402
```

Note that this code is running on a physical iOS device written in Xamarin iOS.

What's causing this error to be thrown?

Comment: The error sounds like it might be while ZipArchive creates its index, during its Dispose at the `}` just before that Seek. If you put some dummy line of code there (e.g. `var t = 0;`), does the exception happen at that line instead? Doesn't solve the problem, but would indicate it isn't the Seek.

Comment: You could try adding  stream.Dispose() after copyto() method of each item.